# Iterate all row in table and select data in another table - jdeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I have a table, call it transaction detail. Above it, i have a submit button. When i click the button, it'll bring popup with a check box from a table called items, and all item in the trans.detail table will be selected in items checkbox.

My question is how to select items in checkbox and update table transaction detail when i Check/uncheck some items in the checkbox?

I hope i explain well. Thanks..

Update : more explanation...

There are 3 tables actually, transaction, transaction detail, and items. One transaction have many trans detail, and on trans detail is coresponding to one item. So in trans detail i have trans.ID and items.ID attribute. I also have a view link..
My use case is, i click a row in trans table, and the transaction detail table will update itself (which is already done). And now when i click "Edit detail button", a popup will appear with items table in it, and item that already in trans detail will be checked in popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an approach similar to this may help: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/99-checkbox-for-delete-in-table-1539659.pdf

Frank

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is not clear to me. A check box can be  bound to an attribute (which can be transient) of the table (items in your case). Now you have to iteratir through transaction detail and set the attribute for the items attribute bound to the checkbox fro the corresponding row. 
You did not mention how the transaction detail and the itwms are related and if you have a view link which connect the two. So I can't give advice on how to find the corresponding row.